# React Js: prevent line breaks or submit on enter in the text area

Tags: reactjs

code:

```
const Chat = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const messages = useSelector(state => state.Chat);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader>
        <p>Chat Bot</p>
        <div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} size="1x" color="white" />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} size="1x" color="white" />
        </div>
      </Styled.ChatHeader>
      <Styled.ChatLog>
        {/* <Styled.MessageWrapper bot={true}>
          <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} bot={true} />
          <Styled.ChatMessage bot={true}>
            dsasasasasasasasasasa
          </Styled.ChatMessage>
        </Styled.MessageWrapper> */}
        {messages.map(message => (
          <Styled.MessageWrapper bot={true}>
            <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} bot={false} />
            <Styled.ChatMessage bot={true}>{message.text}</Styled.ChatMessage>
          </Styled.MessageWrapper>
        ))}
      </Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
        <textarea
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem"
        />
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(sendMessage(text))}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} size="lg" color="black" />
        </button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};
```

Hello I'm in doubt as to how I will not allow line breaks in my textarea and clean it when the button button is pressed
Clear the textarea field when my click event is called

Comment: prevent the enter key press

Comment: this not is in react js

Comment: i try with this and not sucess..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just prevent default for `Enter` like this:

```js
<textarea onKeyPress={e => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter')
     e.preventDefault()
  }}
/>
```

Comment: can i use this same code to instead of breaking the line send my code to my store?

Comment: i have this function for send to my reducer:   const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(sendMessage(text));
    setText('');
  };

Comment: Yes of course, ( I prefer to check ctrl pressed to send, because user may want to send multiline message)

Comment: just make your component controlled and send current value from state

Comment: To check crtl and so on use: `e.ctrlKey`

Comment: i try                if (e.key === 'enter' && e.ctrlKey) {
              handleClick();
            } and dont work

Comment: Try `Enter` carefully with first letter with upper case

Comment: if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey) i try but dont work

Comment: const keydownHandler = e => { const {ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey} = e }
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler)
  return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler)
})